# Can TestCafe be configured with single file reporter

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have been working in TestCafe recently and I need a custom reporter. I was looking for something like [mocha reporter](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Third-party-reporters). But all I could find is generating a plugin and publish it to npm. Is there a way to have a single file reporter?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to have a single file reporter?

You can redirect the reporter's output to the file.

`testcafe chrome test.js -r spec:result.txt`

> I was looking for something like mocha reporter.

TestCafe ships with 5 reporters: spec, list, minimal, xUnit, JSON. Also, many custom reporters can be find in npm: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=testcafe-reporter.